# Driving 60 signals one at a time, in constant sequence

Tags: microcontroller, signal, multiplexer

I have an application where I need to turn on/off one of 60 signals one after another in a constant order, ever repeating. (1, 2, 3, ... 59, 60, 1, 2, ...) Only one signal is on at any given time. The load sinks up to 500 mA each. I'm looking for ideas on how to achieve this in the simplest (not necessarily cheapest) way. Obviously, a large microcontroller or FPGA could do it, but that would be way overkill as the logic for the circuit is very simple.

Comment: Is the order of powering the outputs the same, or does the order vary?

Comment: What signals the change from one to the other? External trigger, time, ... ?

Comment: Do you mean drive output 1 then output 2 then output 3? Or is it more random than that?

Comment: You may wish to research ["Ring Counter"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_counter)

Comment: @Andyaka I think he is asking for a 60-bit ring-counter.

Comment: @nidhin so do I but it's important that saar answers

Comment: A ring counter / SR is one solution. When I posted the question, I was hoping for some non-trivial clever solution ;)

Comment: How fast does the switching from one output to the next occur, or conversely, how long will each output be on for before switching to the next?

Comment: @Olin About a second

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest method is a bank of shift registers with ULN2803s attached to them.  Clock a 1 into the first bit, then clock all 0s into the rest and (if you use a non-latching shift register or a latching one with the latch permanatly in the open state), watch that 1 walk its way up through all your outputs in turn.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the HC595 answer is that it takes no account of the power-on behavior of the shift registers, and there is no guarantee that only one output will be active until either you issue 60 shift commands or you provide another MCU pin to drive all the MR lines.

Another approach, which will take 1 more IC and 3 more MCU lines is to create a 6 to 64 demultiplexer, using something like 74HC138s.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHXDjM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This setup will provide up to 64 output lines, with the selected line low and the others high. If you need active high, use 74HC238s for the right-hand units, but not for the left-hand one. As shown, I've only shown 24 output lines, but you should be able to fill in the intermediate stages.

This takes a couple more control lines from the MCU and an extra 16-pin DIP, but it has a couple of advantages:

1) You can address the desired line directly if you ever need to produce an output sequence that is not strictly 0,1,2, etc

2) There is no need to perform an initialization pulse or set of 60 shifts

3) There is no chance for noise on the shift clock line to produce an inadvertent output.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this easily with the [74HC595](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74hc595.pdf) daisychained to eachother.  The 74HC595 is a serial-in parallel-out shift register, that being you shift in the data, enable a latch, and then the values are set on the output pins all at once.  This could be done with a very simple microcontroller.

With each shift register, you get 8 parallel-out pins.  The control scheme is described by this picture.  You connect the clock and latch lines to each shift register and then the data line is pushed through  the Q7' pin:

[image]

To get your 500ma drive capacity though, you may need to combine this with a current source such as a [M54564P](http://www.mitsubishielectric-mesh.com/products/pdf/m54564p_e.pdf) or [ULN2803](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/uln2803a.pdf), or any other darlington transistor array that is capable of supplying 500mA

Comment: What about the 500 mA load current?

Comment: You can use an M54564P or a ULN2803 to add higher current sourcing capabilities.  these are just darlington transistor arrays